# ODBC.ini Password to MS SQL

Tags: sql-server, password

I want to change password to a more complex one. I have access as SA to the MS SQL database and it's no problem to change the password.
The problem is: I have a odbc.ini for a Windows programm to use.
There the password is stored `J@JCFIJADEGD$-"YKySiAQb` (it's missing one string; [here is the screenshot](https://ibb.co/Lx42r0H))
The clear password stored in the MS SQL is: `niwaz`.

How can I create a new password with a new string to connect?

Comment: Check the application documentation as that is what encrypts/decrypts the password.